# TextInputLayout listener not working on API higher 28

Tags: android, user-interface, android-textinputedittext

I tryed to set setOnFocusChangeListener on textInputLayout. It's working fine on API above 28.
Also, setOnClickListener not working on API above 28. How can i fix it on API higher 28?
My code:

```
  with(binding) {
            textFieldSearch.setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
                Log.d(javaClass.simpleName,"SetOn: Focus")
                if (hasFocus) {
                    textFieldSearch.setStartIconDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search)
                    tabLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    viewpager.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    popularSearchLay.container.visibility = View.GONE
                } else {
                    textFieldSearch.setStartIconDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_arrows_back)
                    tabLayout.visibility = View.GONE
                    viewpager.visibility = View.GONE
                    popularSearchLay.container.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }
}
```

My layout:

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textFieldSearch"
            style="@style/CustomTextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/textInputSearch"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/edit_text_hint_padding"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                android:inputType="textFilter" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

MyStyle:

```
   <style name="CustomTextInputLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopStart">@dimen/searchViewCornerRadius</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd">@dimen/searchViewCornerRadius</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopEnd">@dimen/searchViewCornerRadius</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomStart">@dimen/searchViewCornerRadius</item>
        <item name="borderWidth">@dimen/searchViewBorderWidth</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">@dimen/textFieldMargin</item>
        <item name="android:hint">@string/hint_edit_text</item>
        <item name="hintTextColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="endIconMode">clear_text</item>
        <item name="startIconDrawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_search</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: there is no `setOnChangeClickListener` method for `TextInputLayout`... you may try yo `setOnFocusChangeListener` on `textInputSearch` (not `textFieldSearch`)

Comment: it's not working

Answer (score 0):

```
         textinputSearch.setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
            Log.d(javaClass.simpleName,"SetOn: Focus")
            if (!hasFocus) {
                textinputSearch.setStartIconDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search)
                tabLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                viewpager.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                popularSearchLay.container.visibility = View.GONE
            } else {
                textFieldSearch.setStartIconDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_arrows_back)
                tabLayout.visibility = View.GONE
                viewpager.visibility = View.GONE
                popularSearchLay.container.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
```

use style this in your textinput

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
```

Comment: textInputSearch haven't method setStartIconDrawable

Comment: what do you want?

Comment: I want some views to be displayed or hidden depending on whether the field is in focus or not. And i think the problem is in viewBinding.